# I cannot flag a problem as off-topic and belonging to CS.SE

Tags: feature-request, closing

I find relevant discussions here: [Migration path from cstheory to CS.SE](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1550/46760).

Though, I still think that the frequency we need this function is not that low as stated in the answer.

——————————————

Original post:

The only two options are belonging to StackOverflow and Meta. However I have seen and I will expect many people coming here for asking non-research-level questions which are quite appropriate to be directly moved to CS.SE.

I know that there exists an option to merely flag a question as off-topic and do nothing else. But I think it’s a good idea for us to move further, thereby being more friendly to those people new to CSTheory.SE.